# How to add corner radius to a UIBezier Path Arc

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I am creating an arc using UIBezierPath arc convenience method. I want the ends of the arc to be rounded off - see attached sketch for exact requirement! The cornerRadius option used in the roundedRect version isn't available for the arc method. Anyone got an ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance. (This is different to previously asked question in that it provides exact requirement)

```
 let center = CGPoint(x:bounds.width/2, y: bounds.height/2)
 let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
 let arcWidth: CGFloat = 10
 let startAngle: CGFloat = 4.6 / 3 * π
 let endAngle: CGFloat = 4.4 / 3 * π

 let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius/2 - arcWidth/2, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

 path.lineWidth = arcWidth
 // all thats needed to make the ends rounded is
 path.lineCapStyle = .Round
 path.stroke()
```

[image]

Comment: I don´t know why this question was downvoted because it makes perfectly sense to me. But you should really accept an answer

Comment: hi Philipp, i added the answer myself, please see the comment added to the edited question and my response to EridB's answer below. I hope this helped you. R

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All thats needed is to add one line of code: 
    path.lineCapStyle = .Round.

Answer (score 16):

### Solution

What actually does the trick is lineCap property. You can use the code below.

```
func drawCircle(view: UIView, startingAngle: CGFloat, endAngle: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer {
    let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: view.center, radius: CGFloat((view.bounds.size.height/2) - 10), startAngle: startingAngle, endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true)

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath

    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

    view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    return shapeLayer
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: `lineCap` uses defined constants. Don't use `"round"` use `kCALineCapRound`, `kCALineCapButt` or `kCALineCapSquare`. Please update your answer.

Comment: I was really surprised why this property is a string, and I didn't know that it had a defined constant. Thank you very much for pointing out @Fogmeister

Comment: In reality they are just strings but much better to use the constants just in case things change in the future :D Plus you get compile time checking :D

Comment: Indeed, at that moment I was blaming at Swift safe typing, but you noticed it and I changed opinion :D

Comment: thanks guys above for your detailed answer and pointers to lineCapStyle. But all I actually needed to do was add one line of code path.lineCapStyle = .Round :-)